# Mobile app center Replaces Azure Mobile App services?

Tags: azure, mobile, azure-mobile-services, mobile-center

I'm building a mobile app and I intend to build its backend with Azure Mobile app backend, but according to [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/issues/227) azure mobile app is obsolet, and I fell on Mobile app center recently, My question is should I build the back-end as a normal service and include push notifications using Mobile app center or should I use Azure Mobile Service, Please I need clarification on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a PM in App Center team at Microsoft. We are doing user research right now to understand the evolving needs for these services and plan to build the next generation of Azure Mobile Apps as part of Visual Studio App Center. While we're working on the roadmap, we are fully committed to supporting Azure Mobile Apps including support for the latest OS releases, bug fixes, and documentation updates.

To answer your question, Push Notification service in App Center is in "Preview" right now which means that there could be changes in the service while we are working to make it production ready. We don't recommend to not use this service for your "production apps". You can use Azure Mobile Apps as it stands currently but there won't any new features added to it. Based on your needs, you can make a decision on what service would be best suited for application.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what I though of doing is build my app's backend with .net core (Since mobile apps services still is in aspnet) and use app center's notifications. Do you think I'm on the  right path ? any piece of advice please ?